# Остановка setInterval из прототипа

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Есть конструкция в ходе которой у объекта есть переменная interval и через методы в прототипе этой переменной задаётся setInterval и при нажатии на кнопку этот setInterval должен тормозиться, но этого почему-то не происходит.

```js
class Timer{
  constructor(date){
    this.interval;
  }
  startCount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> console.log('work'), 100);
  }
  stopCount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

let timer = new Timer();
timer.startCount();

document.querySelector('button').onclick = timer.stopCount;
```

```html
<button> stop </button>
```

Comment: Потому что this теряется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
class Timer { 
   constructor(date){
    this.interval;
  }
  startCount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(()=> console.log('work'), 300);
  }
  stopCount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

var timer = new Timer();

document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(){
  timer.startCount();
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  timer.stopCount();
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> start </a>
<button> stop </button>
```